# Load balancing with OPNSense, relayd or haproxy?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, opnsense, relayd

There is two main options for load-balancing in OPNsense (and pfSense): relayd and haproxy. pfSense has removed relayd in favour of haproxy [1,2], but OPNsense still supports it. In what usecases we should prefer using haproxy over relayd (or vice versa)?

- [1] https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/9386
- [2] https://forum.netgate.com/topic/140790/heads-up-relayd-deprecated-on-pfsense-2-5-0/14

P.S. Personally (despite the notes in [1]) I think relayd is a more fittable solution for a firewall, because it uses NAT to load balance, and thus consuming less resources (both CPU and RAM), also states are synced in a HA setup. haproxy gives more options to load balance, but it's more suspectable to misfunction in a high-load environment.

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/172394/326792